# VSC resolves preinstalled imports but not manually installed imports. Why?

Tags: python, numpy, python-import, importerror, python-3.11

I have a problem after I moved my code from Pycharm to Visual Studio Code.
I use the exakt same Interpreter for both.
For my programming I need some imports that i had to manuel install and some that are preinstalled with Python.
That that are preinstalled work perfektly fine but for every pip-installed import, VSC says "import could not be resolved" altrough it works on Pycharm and in cmd just works fine!
When i write in the console for expample "pip install numpy" it says it is installed!
Does anyone know what the problem is?

I try to reinstall Python, all imports and Visual Studio code, but that helped not.
Additionaly I searched the web and stackoverflow if somebody had similar problems and that was the case.
Altrough nobody described the eroor that some imports work and some not, i tryed most of the Suggested solutions but they did nnot helped.
You cant see it on the photo but the code runs WSL: Ubuntu, maybe that helpes.

[In the Terminal its says numpy is installed, right after it says there is no module named numpy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTF8i.png)

[terminal version is 3.11.1 but import is saved in Python3.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ewuC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your picture, on the bottom right, you can see that you are running Python 3.11.1 while your terminal output says that numpy is installed in a Python 3.8 environment.

So it seems like your terminal is working with another environment.
Did you choose your interpreter (probably one with Python 3.8) in VSCode with Ctrl+Shift+P, then type Select Interpreter, then select the interpreter?

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that too. But when I write `python -V` the terminal says Python 3.11.1.
But numpy is installed in python3.8. That makes no sens because i have only installed Python3.11 on my PC and have deleted Python3.8.
I added a photo that shows that!

Comment: But when I make the same on Pycharm so write `python -V` than comes Python 3.11.1 too, but when i write then `pip install numpy` is says it is already satiesfies in "\python\python311\site-packages" so not in PYthon3.8 like VSC says. So that is the problem like you said, thank you!
But i still dont know how to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the cause of the error.
The cause was that I focused on working with the new 3.11 or 3.10 and ignored completly to test if the 3.8 would work.
By a by lucky accident I tried it and it works!